# how to check whether some c++ file got compiled from a bunch of c++ files (after using make command)

Tags: makefile, cmake, multiple-makefiles

i want to know whether modified files got compiled from a bunch of c++ files . I am using "make" command for compiling c++ files.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what your question means. Present an example.

Comment: Can you look for the binary files? Does the makefile produce useful output? Can you modify the makefile?